# set selected item in select by name in controller of angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am working on angularjs , Where I need to set selected item by name in selected item.

How DO i do that . I can set item by index but how do i do with itemname

Eg : on load I am setting 1st item as selected item

```
$scope.internalRoles = data;
                $scope.internalItemSelected = $scope.internalRoles[0];
```

and Data is like

```
 data = [{id : 1 , roleName : "admin"}
,{id : 2 , roleName : "superadmin"}]
```

Now I want to set selected item on basis on roleName

```
$scope.internalItemSelected =  $scope.internalRoles["superadmin"] ;//based on roleName
```

But its not working.

How do i set it by name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a extension for your array:

```
Array.prototype.findItem = function (searchFor) {    
    return this.find(function(item){
       return item['roleName'] === searchFor;
    });
};
```

Then call it with:

```
$scope.internalItemSelected =  $scope.internalRoles.findItem("superadmin");
```

You can also pass 'roleName' as a property of extension to make it more general in use.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if u wants to set name from the selected item then directly do like this

```
$scope.internalRoles = data;
  $scope.internalItemSelected = $scope.internalRoles[0].roleName;
  console.log($scope.internalItemSelected);
```

Comment: my dropdown has both Id as well as rolename ... but I want to set selected item programtically by rolename.. So is there any way i can loop through main data source  with rolename and set matching rolename .. item to selected